# How do newly-created programming languages use Windows API features?

Tags: api, windows

WinAPI is focused primarily on the C family, but how do new programming languages use those features without creating their own runtime/interpreter type thing?  Do they hook directly into the DLL files?  kernel32.dll contains most of those functions right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every language (even C!) has some kind of runtime. This runtime will usually provide bindings to C or have an API usable from C (or in the case of C: from assembler). Such C bindings can then be used to access libraries written for C. There will usually be a translation layer that converts between different data representations in C and in the target language.

Comment: @Jake for more information, please see these Wikipedia articles: [Foreign Function Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface), [Language Binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding).

Comment: The "Foreign Function Interface" is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!